# Reason behind git lock errors

Tags: git

I'm working in a large git repo with hundreds of branches. I'm on Windows. Typically when I `git pull`, it gives me multiple lock errors, eg:

`error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branchname': is at eed24d0d63 but expected e205e065f3`

I can fix this by running `git gc --prune=now` and pulling again. When looking at all the branches of the remote repo, I don't see duplicate branches (with different upper/lowercase names).

Why does this happen?
Why does that command fix it?
Can I prevent it?

Comment: It should not happen in the first place. It suggests that there are multiple different Git processes running simultaneously, stepping on each other.

Comment: Multiple processes running on my machine? Which would make sense given I have Visual Studio running which is attached to my git repo but I tend to do any commands via the git bash.

Comment: Hm, so if VS is doing one thing and you're doing another, that maybe could do it. I don't use Windows (hence don't use VS) so I'm not sure if it has anything to coordinate.

Comment: Do you know in what way the processes are stepping on one another to cause this?

Comment: No, this is all just speculation. In particular two things that are trying to modify some branch (a background `fetch` and ... something else, for instance) might both use a Git internal interface saying "re-set `origin/master` from old-hash to new-hash" but one of them finishes doing so just before the second one starts. But maybe it is some other problem entirely. I've never seen it happen myself.

Comment: I encounter this problem regularly when using GitKraken and bash in parallel. I assume it is the same 'stepping on one another' you talked about, since GK is performing background fetches from time to time and the error ceases when I close GK.

Comment: got that with git on windows after a remote branch rename from uppercase to lowercase. Dunno if both are related