# Git fetch gives "cannot lock ref" error message but seems to work anyway

Tags: git, bitbucket

Sometimes when I try and run `git fetch` I get the following response:

> error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/*branchname*': is at *XXXXXX* but expected *YYYYYY*

The steps that I took that caused  this were, to the best of my recollection, the following:

1. I did a `git push` from my work-PC, as I usually do, to the origin hosted at Bitbucket;
2. I did an uncommon `git fetch` when I got home. There were no errors or warnings;
3. I  did an uncommon `git push` after working at home. There were no errors or warnings;
4. I did a `git fetch` when I arrived at the work today.

Step 4 caused the error message. My local repository had the offending branch checked out. Still I just ran `git pull` and it seemed to work.

This is not the first time I saw this error message. The first time it happened, I fetched another team's repository to update my local copy which had been sitting untouched (no fetching, no work, no pushing) for one month or two. When I pushed my changes, my co-worker got the error.

So in the two cases it seems to be somewhat related to local repositories which stay untouched for a while. But a sample of two is quite small to draw any conclusions.

I'd like to know what could be causing this. And, more importantly, if it is indeed harmless or if I'm at risk of losing work.

Comment: `git gc --prune=now` worked for me (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948281/reason-behind-git-lock-errors )

Comment: `git pull -p` worked for me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Following @bernard-paulus's comment, you can try

```
git gc --prune=now
```

which worked for me

You can also try

```
git for-each-ref
```

Comment: can you explain what is the issue & how it got solved using this command. I googled it, but didn't able to understand

Comment: Neither of these commands worked: I still get the exact same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried multiple options but below command worked for me. Putting it here for others if the above command does not work.

**git pull -p**