# remote rejected with unexpected commit hash

Tags: git

I commit to my own git server and setup a `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Mirror to GitHub"
git push --mirror >>/tmp/git-push.log 2>&1 &

exec git update-server-info
```

this is some error logs in `/tmp/git-push.log`

```
To github.com:honovation/ljmall.git
   2127e2a15..9d8fb51e4  env-ljmall-staging -> env-ljmall-staging
To github.com:honovation/ljmall.git
 ! [remote rejected]     env-ljmall-staging -> env-ljmall-staging (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/env-ljmall-staging': is at 9d8fb51e482705480df71ebc378abb6a6eddca5a but expected 2127e2a157b32303d781401fa9694e5935660df2)
 ! [remote rejected]     ljmall-staging-20180327102841-35b5a8283a20688ca12803980a92f17246ce6c7d -> ljmall-staging-20180327102841-35b5a8283a20688ca12803980a92f17246ce6c7d (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:honovation/ljmall.git'
```

I don't know why Github rejected, the first two lines mean github accept a  `env-ljmall-staging` changes from `2127e2a15` to `9d8fb51e4`, why Github expect the old commit hash (`2127e2a15`)?

Comment: you shoul probably add some header with time to the log. Here it looks like there were 2 runs, and the second has failed

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45948281/6309), this could be the result of multiple process running at the same time on your server, preventing `git` to access and lock a file.

Any amend/reset done locally on your repo should not be a problem, considering a `push --mirror` implies a `push --force` anyway.